# Exclude private country users from DB - Laravel repository

Tags: laravel

I have two users (UserA & UserB). Both users are from Italy, but if UserB is set `country_private` field to true, UserA cannot see UserB.

In `users` table I have `country_field` (true/false). Each user can have many countries.

I tried this:

```
return $model->where(function ($query) use ($country) {
            $query->where('country_private', 1);
            $query->whereHas('countries', function ($query) use ($country) {
                $query->where('name', '!=', $country);
            });
        });
```

This is not working because with UserA I can see UserB. What I'm missing here?

Edit: This is more like country restriction. If I set I don't want to be visible in Italy, no one from Italy cannot see me. I use GeoIP to detect country and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but what about a simple query for User A:

For User A

```
return $model->where('country_private','!=',true)->get();
```

This way, you only get users with country_private set to true for user A (assuming *true* is the default value).

Comment: This is more like country restriction. If I set I don't want to be visible in Italy, no one from Italy cannot see me. I use GeoIP to detect country and filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution myself.

```
return $this->repository->get()->filter(function ($user) use ($country) {
                if ($user->country_private == 0) {
                    return $user;
                }

                return !$user->countries()->where('name', $country)->exists();
            });
```

Comment: This will not scale well, as this performs the filter in code space and not in the database. Just keep that in mind and do as you see fit.

Comment: I know but I couldn't do it better. Do you have some recommendation?

Comment: If I would understand the context better we probably could come up with a query. For now it takes me too much time to understand to be honest

Comment: Gave it another read during the day, what you are looking for is `HAVING` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837058/how-to-select-rows-that-have-certain-relationships-through-a-pivot-tabel

Comment: I use geoip (torann package in laravel) to detect visitor's location. And having users with option to restrict their profiles to certain countries. If I set that field to true and my country is Italy, any visitor from Italy will not see me, but from other countries they will see me.

Comment: You would make it more clear with adding the tables to your question.